# Is it possible to change keyword for cross referencing between grammar rules/objects in Xtext?

Tags: dsl, xtext

When I want to make cross referencing between grammar rules in Xtext work, I need to use keyword `name` for that. E.g.:

```
Constant:
    name=NAME_TERMINAL "=" number=Number;

ConstUsage:
    constant=[Constant | NAME_TERMINAL];
```

Is it possible to change this word to another one (e.g. `id`) ? I need it e.g. in case when I have rule, which uses parameter `name` for something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a custom implementation of `IQualifiedNameProvider` e.g. by subclassing `DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider`.

```
public class MyDslQNP extends DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider{

    QualifiedName qualifiedName(Element e) {
        Package p = (Package) e.eContainer();
        return QualifiedName.create(p.getName(), e.getId());
    }

}
```

see https://dietrich-it.de/xtext/2011/07/16/iqualifiednameproviders-in-xtext-2-0.html for the complete example